# Excel VBA count numbers before and after decimal

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to count the numbers before and after a decimal place.

For example 1452.13 before would be 4 before and after would be 2.

The value is stored in a string i think i may need to use the len with find but cannot figure it out?

would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can I play too? :D

```
Num = 1452.13
Debug.Print Len(Split(Num, ".")(0)) '<~~ Length of number before decimal
Debug.Print Len(Split(Num, ".")(1)) '<~~ Length of number After decimal
```

EDIT:

I am assuming that you will pass only decimals. But to make it foolproof, you can use this

```
Num = 1452

Debug.Print Len(Split(Num, ".")(0)) '<~~ Length of number before decimal

If InStr(1, Num, ".") Then Debug.Print Len(Split(Num, ".")(1)) _
Else Debug.Print 0 '<~~ Length of number After decimal
```

Comment: `Len(Split(Num & ".", ".")(1))`

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what you are trying to say?

Comment: Consider `Num = 1452`, add dot concatenation to make the code failproof.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean :D I am assuming that OP will always pass a decimal. Else I would have used INSTR :D But good point though!

Comment: @HarveyFrench: that is what omegastripes was saying and I did reply to that comment. However to avoid any confusion, I have updated the post :)

Answer (score 5):

There a loads of ways.  eg [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/601323-visual-basic-applications-function-find-number-decimal-places.html)

This is quite a fast technique to find digits after the decimal point.

It can be copied and modified to find the places before the decimal point

```
Function CountDecimalPlaces(aNumber As Double) As Long

    Dim len1 As Long, len2 As Long
    len1 = Len(CStr(aNumber))
    len2 = Len(CStr(Int(aNumber)))
    CountDecimalPlaces = len1 - len2 + CLng(len1 <> len2)

End Function


Function CountInteger(aNumber As Double) As Long

    CountInteger = Len(CStr(Int(aNumber)))

End Function
```

Neither of the above rely on you decimal character being a "."

Comment: ++ for multiple solutions! (I think (minus) **-** `CLng(len1 <> len2)` should be **+** `CLng(len1 <> len2)`)

Comment: I know - very clever, but what do you get when you evaluate `CLng(len1 <> len2)` during execution? (I get a -1)

Answer (score 2):

Using an excel formula you would be best to use the following (fast) formulas

```
=LEN(INT(A1))  

=LEN(A1) - IF(INT(A1)-A1,1,0) - LEN(INT(A1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEN(LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(".";A1))-1)
=LEN(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(".";A1)))
```

That is, if your decimal character is a dot.

Comment: I have a decimal separator and both return 2 (for 1452.13 in A1)

Comment: =LEN(INT(A1)) and =LEN(A1-INT(A1))-2 is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Microsoft Word:

```
Sub dot()

Dim Num As Variant
Num = 1452.13
MsgBox "You number: " & Num
MsgBox "Length of number before decimal: " & Len(Split(Num, ".")(0))
MsgBox "Length of number After decimal: " & Len(Split(Num, ".")(1))

End Sub
```

Based on Siddharth Rout answer

Comment: Think there are no new insights; if you want to make the code really foolproof (look at @Siddharth-Rout 's edit) then use the local decimal settings that can differ from the usual point delimiter "." (comma as used in central Europe, e.g. in Germany or Austria). BTW this is VBA code not only valid for MS Word.

Comment: You are correct @T.M. the difference is the ´Debug.Print´ Siddrath didn't mention that the results are at the Imrmediate Window. If one is a beginner could have problems watching the results. I'd like to know your opinion.

Comment: It is fine that you intend to help, but I think even a beginner could have a look at the MS help site, if he doesn't know what's the meaning of `Debug.Print`. IMO this addition isn't really connected with the question itself or an urgent need for clarification :-)